# How to combine string using ,

Tags: javascript

I want to combine the string

My given input is

```
"the, quick, brown, 'fox, name fred', jumps"
```

My output I want is

```
the quick browm 'fox, name fred' jumps
```

JavaScript code

```
    var a = "the, quick, brown, 'fox, name', jumps".split(",").join(" "); 

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
 {
document.write(a[i]);
}
```

I get the output when I use document.write but when I use console.log everything is messed can someone help me out please

my output is

```
t,
h,
e,
q,
u,
I,
```

Comment: Use repleace instead.
a.replace(",", "");

Comment: I am getting all line break one piece by one piece.

Comment: That's because you use document.write()

Comment: `"when I use console.log everything is messed"` - What does that even mean?  What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: all the line is break one by one  so for instance a

Comment: Why is the input in your code different from the one in your description? Why are you trying to iterate over a string you just .`join()`ed?

Comment: @danny: That still doesn't clarify what you mean.  (You didn't even finish your sentence.)  Maybe you can demonstrate in the question?

Comment: Yes, sorry my sentence was cut down,  what I am trying to do is trying to get the following output but output is all breaking up line by line.

Comment: clearly a homework problem. anyone who helps is degrading the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
var input = "the, quick, brown, 'fox, name fred', jumps";
var output = input.replace(/,/g, "");
```

**Update**: OP mentions that he wants to exclude the commas within single quotes from being replaced.

```js
var input = "the, quick, brown, 'fox, name fred', jumps";
//Replace all the commas except for the ones in single quotes.
var strings = input.split(/'/g);
var newStrings = [];
for(var i=0;i<strings.length;i++) {
  if(i%2 === 0)
     newStrings[i] = strings[i].replace(/,/g, "");
  else 
    newStrings[i] = strings[i];
}
console.log(newStrings.join('\''));
```

Comment: String.replace isn't recursive. Use `input.replace(/,/g, "")`

Comment: the only problem is I have inclide ' fox, name fred'  comma inside the quotation

Comment: @danny and???? did you try this on your own? I understand your new, but you seriously need to debug this stuff on your own if you want to make it in the industry. We're problem solvers.

Comment: I completely agree I flag this question becase I was stuck with this for long time, I requested the moderator to delete this question. other all the code I have return is. I was just stuck at this particular point

Comment: @danny, see my edits and let us know if it addresses your additional needs.  If it does, please vote accordingly.

Comment: I gave you up for best answer but I was not allow to use any regex value.  I am trying on my own without regex value

Comment: I am so lost I m trying to convert the code you provide without using regex but I m so lost. Can you help me out without using regex

Comment: @danny, you should have mentioned that in your question that you didn't want to use regex. Anyway, you can still do it in a `for` loop like the way you currently have. Only thing is that you will have to put `if` condition in the loop to look for a quote in addition to a comma. Once a quote is found, stop replacing the comma until you find the next quote, at which point you will resume replacing the commas.

Comment: @VHS that's the part I am being stuck  and trying to figure out how to put quote and comma in if statement